# SimpleDateFormat.parse() converts DTstring to local time. Can be converted to source's time?

Tags: java, android, datetime, android-date

I have followed this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18217193/1447885) for datetime conversion of 8601.

I will cite an example [straight from w3](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) :

```
1994-11-05T08:15:30-05:00 corresponds to November 5, 1994, 8:15:30 am, US Eastern Standard Time.

1994-11-05T13:15:30Z corresponds to the same instant.
```

And this is what I run in android

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfSource = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ");
dateTime = sdfSource.parse("2014-03-06T11:30:00-05:00");
System.out.println(dateTime); //Thu Mar 06 18:30:00 EET 2014
```

Obviously [.parse()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29)'s output is the local aware datetime. There has been a conversion  from `EST`(-05:00) to `EET` (+02:00) since now I am in this timezone. However I do not want this auto-convertion.

Is there a way to parse a datetime string in`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ` format and display **THAT timezone's** datetime? Preferable output:

```
Thu Mar 06 11:30:00 EST 2014
```

The `EST` and my location is an example. It can be any other timezones as well.

Answer (score 2):

Internally `Date` objects are in UTC and that's what they're parsed to.

You cannot retrieve the original timezone from the `Date` but you can attempt to retrieve it from the original ISO-8601 stamp, and use it when formatting.

When you convert it to a string with `toString()`, it uses your local settings to format the date. If you want a specific representation, use a formatter to format the output, e.g.

```
int rawTimeZoneOffsetMillis = ...; // retrieve from ISO-8601 stamp and convert to milliseconds
TimeZone tz = new SimpleTimeZone(rawTimeZoneOffsetMillis, "name");

DateFormat outputFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
outputFormat.setTimeZone(tz);
System.out.println(df.format(dateTime));
```

ISO-8601 timestamps are not completely parseable with `SimpleDateFormat`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10621553/101361) has some code to work around some of the limitations.

Comment: The limitations your are talking about is the `Z` aren't you? Also two things: I use `int rawTimeZoneOffsetMillis = dateTime.getTimezoneOffset()*1000` as the simplest way but I get a deprecation warning. And more importantly `TimeZone tz = new TimeZone();` gives an error:
`Cannot instantiate the type TimeZone`.

Comment: Additionally, Java `Date` cannot represent microseconds resolution like ISO-8601 stamps can. Overlooked the docs, `TimeZone` is abstract and you should use `SimpleTimeZone` instead. The deprecated `Date.getTimezoneOffset()` returns the offset of the *current* timezone, not that that was there in the original stamp.

Answer (score 0):

Although you should not be worried while parsing the date as it is parsed to correct value can be displayed in any format or timezone you want.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfSource = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ");
sdfSource.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getTimeZone( "EST" ) );
dateTime = sdfSource.parse("2014-03-06T11:30:00-05:00");
System.out.println(sdfSource.format(dateTime)); //Thu Mar 06 18:30:00 EET 2014
```

Comment: Thanks but I want a `Thu Mar 06 11:30:00 EST 2014` output.

Comment: Yes still prints `Thu Mar 06 18:30:00 EET 2014`

Comment: i will. Check my edited ans it will work. Laalto has explained how it works. The thing is date only has one long value that can be converted in any format you want, for that you need to call format function to get formated string

Answer (score 0):

Use sdfSource.setTimeZone() method

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfSource = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ");
sdfSource.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST")); //give the timezone you want
dateTime = sdfSource.parse("2014-03-06T11:30:00-05:00");
System.out.println(dateTime); //Thu Mar 06 18:30:00 EET 2014
```

This should do fine.

Comment: Thanks but I want a `Thu Mar 06 11:30:00 EST 2014` output as I say in vipul's answer.